# datetime.time in a tuple shows datetime.datetime instead value

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-datetime

in the below code snippet, I use a loop to append missing hours in a list of tuples

```
hours = []

for i in range(24):
    hours.append(dt.time(i, 0))

for an hour in hours: # this loop prints in the str format "HH:MM: SS"
    print(hour)

for hour in hours:
    check = True
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == hour:
            check = False
            break
    if check == True:
        rows.append((hour, None, None))

for row in rows: # This loop prints datetime.time(H,0)
    print(row)
```

The problem is that when printing DateTime. time object in the tuple (second loop) the output is:

> datetime.time(H,0)

However when the datetime.time is in a list (first loop) it prints in the correct format:

> "HH:MM: SS"

How can I insert datetime. time with the second format in a tuple?

Comment: Why is there a space between `an hour` in the second for loop?

Comment: If you want the text version of `dt.time(i, 0)` you should cast to it. As it is now these elements are `<class 'datetime.time'>`. The reason for the different results is that this class has differing `__str__` and `__repr__` formats. A Container’s `__str__` uses contained objects’ `__repr__` so when printing just the class you use the `__str__` but when it is in a list you end up printing `__repr__` for these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the difference between `str` and `repr` in Python. The first loop is printing the `datetime` object as a `str`. The second loop is outputting as a `repr`, a type of string representation in Python that is mainly used for debugging.

You can use the `str()` function to force the `datetime` object to print as a string, like this:

```py
for tup in rows:
    print(str(tup[0]), tup[1], tup[2])
```

Comment: Your tuple currently contains a datetime object at index zero. If you want it to contain a string object instead, change your append to something like this: `rows.append((str(hour), None, None)) `